# CruiseControl.NET, Visual Studio & SubVersion

Tags: visual-studio, svn, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am setting up a Continuous Integration server.

I have one issue that doesn't seem to be mentioned in the tutorials.

I have a ASP.net Web Application that I need to compile and them publish.

My Problem is that I seem to be able to compile the app but when I attempt to use a buildPublisher this copies every thing including .svn files & folders and ms CS files.

I am using an MSBuild task to compile my source. I tried setting my MSBuild Output Directory to directory but this didn't seem to have any effect.

What am I not understanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the _CopyWebApplication directive:

http://blogs.msdn.com/nmoreau/archive/2007/01/26/deploying-web-application-projects.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We use CruiseControl.NET to deploy our ASP.NET applications to our test servers for the QA department so this is indeed possible.

In each project we created an additional build configuration called 'Deployer' which is identical to the Debug configuration with the exception of building an additional Web Deployment Project. So by running MSBuild in the Deployer configuration we can generate our compiled output in a known location.

We then use NAnt to perform a simple copy operation to the required location, i.e. into a folder where our IIS server is configured to look for the applications.

I know you don't mention NAnt in your question but it's well worth getting familiar with it if you want to get the most out of CCNet.

I'm not at work at the moment but if this makes any sense and you want some additional information then let me know and I'll pull some more information together.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Are your `bin` or `obj` folders checked into svn? if so that would contribute or possibly cause this issue.

Because those folders shouldn't have any svn folders/files

Answer (score 0):

You can configure SVN to call the .svn folders _svn instead.

Set the [SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/asp-dot-net-hack.txt) environment variable.